# Specifying iFrame src from an HTML form

Tags: javascript

Newby to iFrames and I'm curious how I would specify the iFrame "src" from a basic html form? Something similar to how Optimizely works - User specifies their your own URL, URL loads into the iFrame on the next page.

Looking to use Javascript entirely to do this, if possible. Any help or a sense of direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it directly by setting the `src` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('IDOfYourIframe').src = userValue;
```

The `userValue` can come from any source.  For example, it can come from a textbox.

```
userValue = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value
```